# Simple select query gives error

Tags: php, mysqli

Does anyone have any idea why I get two errors for such a simple query? Error message are:

> Warning: mysqli::prepare(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in (...)/functions.php on line 503
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on null in (...)functions.php on line 504

```
$query_select = ("SELECT * FROM vat WHERE vat_status = ?");
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query_select); // line 503
$stmt->bind_param("s", $vat_status); 
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$count = $stmt->num_rows();

$stmt->bind_result ($vat_id          ,
                    $vat_rate        ,
                    $vat_account     ,
                    $vat_description ,
                    $vat_status      ,
                    $vat_timestamp   );
```

Comment: first off, turn on error reporting and add a `die($mysqli->error)` on that line to find out, and here the way how to use `SELECT *` with `->bind_param` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php#85470 or just use `->get_result()`, less hassle

Comment: I would suggest to use the error log file instead of visible error reporting. But in general it is true that you have to add error handling to your code which helps in finding the cause of why something fails.

Comment: That the `prepared` statement complains is 'less than good'. Whatever happens from there is not going to lead to 'reliable' results. The fact this happened on line 500+ is 'interesting'. Could you collect all the relevant information and put together this query with the required data in a file that just runs that query?. To debug it I would `var_dump` - `$stmt`, $vat_status. I would also predefine all the output variables.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was triggering an UPDATE statement and then an SELECT statement, and both of them used `$stmt` variable.  That was what went wrong.

Now I use

```
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

Which really closes the $stmt and frees the result, so I can trigger after an update, the select statement.

Comment: But actually, then i still have the question, why on earth you woyuld use $stmt->close(); instead of mysqli_stmt_close($stmt_insert);?